# What could help initialising GLX to make spyder launch on server?

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, spyder, glx

**Background**

I'm stuck at opening spyder on a remote Linux server which I access via x2Go from windows 10 via a secured connection from my university .I'm not familiar with Linux but my colleague set up an account for me,  which worked fine until I needed an extra module that downgraded a lot of package, which I tried to solve by myself and messed up my system (using `pip` and reinstalling conda not knowing what I was doing, damn)

I have my user account home/bianca but my anaconda distribution has been reinstalled in `media/bianca/software/anaconda3/` by my colleague. There is a spyder3 and a spyder4 in a new environment with

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.1 qt=5.6.2 spyder
```

as given here: [Python spyder could not initialize GLX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291236/python-spyder-could-not-initialize-glx).

**Problem**

if I **call spyder3 in my base env**, no pop-up appears and I get the error

```
Could not initialize GLX
Aborted (core dumped)
```

--> looks like the communication of my windows and the linux via the xserver is wrong.

but
if I **open spyder4 from a new environment**, the spyder4 loading screen appears, blinks, then the program opens (where I can see my last scripts used some other time are being loaded) and crashes:

```
Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Calling the default spyder of the system on some other disk there is no problem (but I don't have my modules)

From the terminal it all works

**What I tried**

- delete all python paths
- conda spyder --reset,
- we deleted a lot of files in home/bianca
- find some kind of initialisation file that stores the last opened
  scripts (not found, is it in `home/bianca/.config/spyder-py3`?

Can it be that there is some erroneous link in there, can I delete that one?

Thanks very much for any suggestion, I'll gladly give more specifications!!

Bianca

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This could be fixed in our next version (4.1.0), to be released in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm using Spyder 4.1.3 on an Ubuntu which I connect via X2Go from Windows10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, also using x2go. After trying everything that you tried, the only solution I found was to launch spyder in a different way. Before this, I would so as follows (and it worked perfectly):

```
source activate [name of your virtual environment]
spyder&
```

Since last week, the 'spyder&' command no longer launches the IDE, and I managed to surpass this by writing instead:

```
source activate [name of your virtual environment]
spyder3
```

The terminal still complains about certain issues, but at least I can work now!

Comment: I was working with version 4 and changing to version 3 seems to have worked for me.

Comment: If you have any issue, ```spyder --reset``` after activating the environment may also help. After that, try either ```spyder``` or ```spyder3``` again.