# QApplication breaks when importing QWebEnginePage on RasPi 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, python-3.8, qtwebengine

My code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage

print("this code is reached")
app = QApplication(["foo"])
print("this code is not reached")
```

results in the error:

```
this code is reached
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
Could not initialize GLX
```

However, if I don't import QWebEnginePage (just uncomment line 3), the code works.

My system: Ubuntu 20.04, RaspberryPi 4B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=none` solves the problem. However I am wondering whether it could be solved without disabling OpenGL. Answer coming from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291236/python-spyder-could-not-initialize-glx) mentioned by Teejay Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291236/python-spyder-could-not-initialize-glx) I would see if the recommended answer fixes your issue

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```